# How to have two Disabled property for a single button in angular?

Tags: angular

I already have one disabled property which corresponds to three buttons based on the condition.
Now once start button is clicked i need to disable it ,how can i do that?.How can we implement multiple disabled property for single button.
Note-input variable cannot be used as it is for a seperate condition

```
<button type="button"  [disabled]="input" (click)="start(tId,uid)">START</button></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the OR operator, then set the 2nd variable value when the button is clicked.

```
<button type="button" [disabled]="input || startClicked" (click)="start(tId,uid); startClicked = true">START</button></p>
```